# Can every bijection f: $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ be written as the composition of at most two (other) such bijections with order 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I came across a problem stating any element $\sigma$ in $S(\mathbb Z )$, the set of bijections from $\mathbb Z$ to itself, can be written as $\sigma = \tau_1 \tau_2$ with $\tau_i \in S(\mathbb Z)$ having order at most two, i.e. $\tau_i(\tau_i(x))=x$. Is this true (I assume the book is correct!) and if so what’s the idea of a proof?

For example I can’t even find such $\tau_i$ for the bijection defined by the cycle $( 1 2 3 4 5 6)$. An example given in the book was $\sigma = x+1 = 1-(-x) = \tau_1 \tau_2$ where $\tau_1 = 1-x, \tau_2 = -x$ which indeed have order 2.

Comment: For finite sets, any element of $S_n$ is a product of disjoint cyclic permutations, and cyclic permutations are a product of two order $2$ permutations as in the example.

Comment: @KentaS That proves that any permutation is a product of several transpositions, but the question ask about a factorization as a product of **two** permutations.

Comment: @jjagmath No, it really does prove the claim, from disjointness. Let $\sigma\in S_n$ decompose as a product of disjoint cyclic permutations $\tau_1\cdots \tau_n$, where each $\tau_i$ is a cyclic permutation, with disjoint support. Then the construction above shows each $\tau_i$ can be factored as $\tau_{i1}\circ\tau_{i2}$ for some order two permutations $\tau_{i1}$ and $\tau_{i2}$ supported on the support of $\tau_i$. Now, since the $\tau_i$'s have disjoint support, $\tau_{ij}$ and $\tau_{kl}$ commute for $i\ne k$. Thus, $\sigma=(\tau_{11}\cdots\tau_{n1})\cdot(\tau_{12}\cdots\tau_{n2})$.

Comment: Here the permutation $\tau_{11}\cdots\tau_{n1}$ has order $2$, again since $\tau_{11},\dots,\tau_{n1}$ commutes with each other, and each $\tau_{i1}$ has order $2$. The same argument applies for $\tau_{12}\cdots\tau_{n2}$.

Comment: @KentaS Then, how would you write, for example, $(1234)$ as a product of two permutations of order $2$?

Comment: @KentaS kudos for the right argument, which is really about dihedral groups. It works for infinite sets as well. Please write it up as a detailed answer - I was going to do that, but the credit for the idea is yours.

Comment: @jjagmath This is a cyclic permutation, so the construction mentioned in the textbook works: compose $x\mapsto -x$ with $x\mapsto 1-x$. Explicitly, $(1234)=(14)(23)\circ(13)$.

Comment: Just to expand on the argument of @KentaS, for $A$ being the integers, or the integers modulo $n$, consider the two maps $x \mapsto - x$ and $x \mapsto -x + 1$. These are clearly involutions, and their composition $\tau_{1} \circ \tau_{2}$ (left-to-right) is the cycle $x \mapsto x+1$. Do this for every orbit of $\langle \sigma \rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, I understood when you mentioned the dihedral group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will first treat the finite case, as it is indicative of the strategy in the $S(\mathbb Z)$ case.

For any element $\sigma\in S_n$, it is known that $\sigma$ is a product of disjoint cyclic permutations. That is, $\sigma=(k_1\cdots k_r)(\ell_1\cdots\ell_m)\cdots$ where $\{k_1,\dots,k_r\}$ and $\{\ell_1,\dots,\ell_m\}$ are disjoint, so on. The idea is, the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ can be decomposed into sets of the form $\{\sigma^i(k)\}_{i\in\mathbb Z}$. Then, it is clear that $\sigma$ acts cyclically on such sets.

Each cycle $(k_1\cdots k_r)$ decomposes as the product of the two permutations $k_i\mapsto k_{-i}$ and $k_i\mapsto k_{1-i}$, as described in the example in the textbook. Now, $\sigma$ decomposes as the product:
$$\sigma=((k_i\mapsto k_{1-i})(\ell_i\mapsto\ell_{1-i})\cdots)\circ ((k_1\mapsto k_{-i})(\ell_i\mapsto \ell_{-i})\cdots),$$
where both these compositions have order $2$.

**Example:** Say $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\2&3&1&5&4\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\sigma$ decomposes as $(123)\circ(45)$. The textbook tells us how to decompose $(123)$ and $(45)$ as a product of two order $2$ permutations: $(123)=(13)\circ(12)$ and $(45)=(45)\circ id$. Thus, $\sigma=(13)(45)\circ(12)id$ is the desired decomposition.

---

For $S(\mathbb Z)$: Now, the set $S(\mathbb Z)$ decomposes into sets of the form $A_k:=\{\sigma^i(k)\}_{i\in\mathbb Z}$. Now, there are two possibilities: $A_k$ is finite, or $A_k$ is infinite. If $A_k$ is finite, then the construction in the textbook tells us the action of $\sigma$ on $A_k$ decomposes into a product of two order $2$ permutations supported on $A_k$. Otherwise, if $A_k$ is infinite, the same formula still works! Consider the two permutations $\sigma^i(k)\mapsto\sigma^{-i}(k)$ and $\sigma^i(k)\mapsto\sigma^{1-i}(k)$.

*More formally*, let $\sigma\in S(\mathbb Z)$ be an arbitrary bijection $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$. Then, for $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, defining $a\sim b$ iff there exists an integer $i$ such that $a=\sigma^i(b)$ defines an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z$. Let $A$ be the set of representatives for $\mathbb Z/\sim$. Then, define the two permutations:
$$\tau_1\colon\sigma^i(k)\mapsto\sigma^{-i}(k)$$
and
$$\tau_2\colon\sigma^i(k)\mapsto\sigma^{1-i}(k),$$
where $k\in A$. Once can check these functions are well-defined, they have order $2$, and that moreover $\sigma=\tau_2\circ\tau_1$.